# WordPress: displaying "More posts" button only if number of posts > 3

Tags: php, wordpress

**UPDATE** I'm actually trying to display a "More Posts" button only if there are more than 3 posts in the "News" category. The current code that I've come up with after searching Stack Overflow is as follows... but doesn't seem to be functioning properly:

```
<?php
$cat = get_query_var('cat');
$posts = get_posts(array('News' => $cat));
if(count($posts) > 3)
{
 echo('<div class="more-box"><a href="#">More news and events</a></div>');
}
else
{
//CODE EXECUTED IF LESS THAN THREE POSTS EXIST IN CURRENT CATEGORY
}
?>
```

How would display the More Button only if there are >3 posts in **News**?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks properly without that line:

```
$posts = get_posts(array('News' => $cat));
```

Function `get_posts` doesn't have parameter `News`. If `$cat` is acronym of *category* then you should have something like this:

```
$posts = get_posts(array('category' => $cat));
```

Then Wordpress should return list of `WP_Post` objects. Also to count posts you can use another internal function:

```
 <?php wp_count_posts( $type, $perm ); ?>
```

Where:

`$type` (string) (optional) Post type to count

`$perm` (string) (optional) To include private posts readable by the current user, set to 'readable' - Default: empty string

Read more: [`wp_count_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts), [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Sorry, I should've clarified... I meant to say that I'm looking to display the code only if there are >3 posts in the "News" category. Would that still be the same code above? How do I apply it only to "News" posts?

Comment: Thank you, Grzegorz... how would I use this same code to check if there are > 3 posts in the "News" category only? Thanks!